# How do I make angular.js reevaluate / recompile inner html?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, interpolation

I'm making a directive that modifies it's inner html. Code so far:

```
.directive('autotranslate', function($interpolate) {
    return function(scope, element, attr) {
      var html = element.html();
      debugger;
      html = html.replace(/\[\[(\w+)\]\]/g, function(_, text) {
        return '<span translate="' + text + '"></span>';
      });
      element.html(html);
    }
  })
```

It works, except that the inner html is not evaluated by angular. I want to trigger a revaluation of `element`'s subtree. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You have to `$compile` your inner html like

```
.directive('autotranslate', function($interpolate, $compile) {
    return function(scope, element, attr) {
      var html = element.html();
      debugger;
      html = html.replace(/\[\[(\w+)\]\]/g, function(_, text) {
        return '<span translate="' + text + '"></span>';
      });
      element.html(html);
      $compile(element.contents())(scope); //<---- recompilation 
    }
  })
```

Comment: Here's what I'm using it for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21483857/add-another-custom-interpolator-in-angularjs/21489208#21489208

Comment: IMHO it's not correct to re-compile an already compiled element (see the problems reported in @kornfridge's solution below).

Comment: @jerico Inside of `link` function must you have to compile again when you are manipulating your `DOM` unless you are using `compile` function. You mentioned @kornfridge's solution, he used `compile` function. According to documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler#the-difference-between-compile-and-link i don't think this is the proper use case to use `compile` function.

Comment: @Reza: IMO the compile function works but is not the best solution either. The OP's intent could probably best be met by manipulating markup on the server, [through an interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) or in the [template cache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache) *before* compilation. This makes for a highly performant and stable solution as it completely removes the need for Angular bindings in translation. See how Google's [DoubleClick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ee3Ecw8rl1Y) did it (starts around 42:34 in the video).

Comment: @Reza: The documentation you cite states that the compile function is to manipulate the structure of the markup while the link function is just to bind it to a scope. As the OP wants to manipulate the markup including the bindings, I'd say that is quite obviously a use case of the compile function (but see my other comment for a better solution in this special case).

Comment: Added an up-vote here for the last line with  $compile... using element.contents() instead of elements.html() was not obvious and got me hung up. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

Here's a more generic method [I developed](http://kent.doddsfamily.us/kcd-angular/#/kcd-recompile) to solve this problem:

```
angular.module('kcd.directives').directive('kcdRecompile', function($compile, $parse) {
  'use strict';
  return {
    scope: true, // required to be able to clear watchers safely
    compile: function(el) {
      var template = getElementAsHtml(el);
      return function link(scope, $el, attrs) {
        var stopWatching = scope.$parent.$watch(attrs.kcdRecompile, function(_new, _old) {
          var useBoolean = attrs.hasOwnProperty('useBoolean');
          if ((useBoolean && (!_new || _new === 'false')) || (!useBoolean && (!_new || _new === _old))) {
            return;
          }
          // reset kcdRecompile to false if we're using a boolean
          if (useBoolean) {
            $parse(attrs.kcdRecompile).assign(scope.$parent, false);
          }

          // recompile
          var newEl = $compile(template)(scope.$parent);
          $el.replaceWith(newEl);

          // Destroy old scope, reassign new scope.
          stopWatching();
          scope.$destroy();
        });
      };
    }
  };

  function getElementAsHtml(el) {
    return angular.element('<a></a>').append(el.clone()).html();
  }
});
```

You use it like so:

HTML

```
<div kcd-recompile="recompile.things" use-boolean>
  <div ng-repeat="thing in ::things">
    <img ng-src="{{::thing.getImage()}}">
    <span>{{::thing.name}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$scope.recompile = { things: false };
$scope.$on('things.changed', function() { // or some other notification mechanism that you need to recompile...
  $scope.recompile.things = true;
});
```

### Edit

If you're looking at this, I would seriously recommend looking at [the website's](http://kent.doddsfamily.us/kcd-angular/#/kcd-recompile) version as that is likely to be more up to date.

Comment: @Adam Barthelson, haha, thanks :-) I actually updated this on my site recently. So I would recommend looking at the site's version.

Comment: Can this directive be used to trigger a recompliation in angular 1.2? Do I have to use one-time binding expressions from angular 1.3?

Comment: Can someone explain me:
`return angular.element('<a></a>').append(el.clone()).html();`

Comment: Yes, `.html()` returns the contents of the element. Because we also want the root node of `el`, we first insert it into a fake element and then get the contents of that.

Comment: Access to the $parent scope from within a directive breaks encapsulation. If you want to do that then you should require a parent directive (see the require-attribute of the Angular directive configuration object) to establish such a dependency in a supported way.

Comment: @kentcdodds - sorry for the asking here ... but can you see anything wrong in the way I'm using the directive? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjWGKd?editors=101

Comment: You're specifying `xcd-use-boolean`. It should be: `kcd-use-boolean`

Comment: Thanks, but that's not all - I created a question to stop polluting this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30650619/5246

Answer (score 10):

This turned out to work even better than @Reza's solution

```
.directive('autotranslate', function() {
  return {
    compile: function(element, attrs) {
      var html = element.html();
      html = html.replace(/\[\[(\w+)\]\]/g, function(_, text) {
        return '<span translate="' + text + '"></span>';
      });
      element.html(html);
    }
  };
})
```

Reza's code work when `scope` is the scope for all of it child elements. However, if there's an ng-controller or something in one of the childnodes of this directive, the scope variables aren't found. However, with this solution ^, it just works!

Comment: @kornifridge can you make it clear `Reza's code work when scope is the scope for all of it child elements` ? and how it is better ? according to documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler#the-difference-between-compile-and-link the best practice of use `compile` function is `Any operation which can be shared among the instance of directives should be moved to the compile function for performance reasons.`