# How to refresh only the templateUrl in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

How can I refresh the injected template in angular with a button, because I tried to do this:

```
$scope.refreshData = function() {
  console.log("Trying to refresh...");
  $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
}
```

When this icon gets clicked:

```
<i class="fa fa-refresh pull-right" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="refreshData();"></i>
```

But the problem is, that the entire page gets refreshed, tbh I'm still learning angularJs.

Thanks.

Comment: You can `$compile` again the template. [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487617/how-do-i-make-angular-js-reevaluate-recompile-inner-html)

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. What do you mean by refresh your template?

Comment: The entire page is refreshed or only the content inside ui-view is refreshed? Because ui-view is the templateUrl..

Comment: The problem is that you're using $state.current.  That means all states will refresh.  You want to refresh only the specific state, so use $state.go(stateYouWantRefreshed) instead.

Comment: Well in the main html file, there are some "widgets (html templates)" that are injected , and each widget has a refresh button, but when the refresh button is clicked, the whole page gets refreshed, instead only the widget, only the widget has to be refreshed.  @Kindzoku

Comment: @ChrisStanley I looked through the code and I guess that the html files are injected with this

 `$http.get('modules/dashboard/partials/listWidgets.json').
            success(function(data) {
                $scope.dashboardItems = data;
                configDashboardMobile();
            }).
            error(function() {
                console.log('Error en la obtención de datos');
            });`

and in the html :

`<div dashboard-items="dashboardItems></div>"`

I couldn't find the states for each widget (html template)